# How can I use brace expansion in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Suppose I want to have the following specs:

```
it { should allow_value("git://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/").for(:url) }
it { should allow_value("git://user@host.xz/path/to/repo.git/").for(:url) }
it { should allow_value("git://host.xz:123/path/to/repo.git/").for(:url) }
it { should allow_value("git://user@host.xz:123/path/to/repo.git/").for(:url) }
...
```

It would be easier and more compact if I could write:

```
"git://{user@,}host.xz{:123,}/path/to/repo.git".expand.each do |p|
  it { should allow_value(p).for(:url) }
end
```

Or even better:

```
"{git,ssh,http,https,rsync}://[user@]host.xz[:123]/path/to/repo.git[/]".expand.each do |p|
  it { should allow_value(p).for(:url) }
end
```

What are some ways to achieve this in Ruby?

**Edit**
The first thing I tried was [bracecomp](https://rubygems.org/gems/bracecomp), but I couldn't get it to work in 1.9.3.

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'bracecomp'
[2] pry(main)> 'server-{a,b}-{07..10}'.expand
TypeError: scan() yielded Symbol (must be Array[2])
from bracecomp.y:66:in `scan'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
%w[git ssh http https rsync].product(['user@', nil], [':123', nil]).each do |protocol, user, port|
  it { should allow_value("#{protocol}://#{user}host.xz#{port}/path/to/repo.git").for(:url) }
end
```

No dependencies on external libraries and understandable to every Ruby developer.

Although this does scream for a spec helper or a custom matcher, I think.

Answer (score 1):

[bracecomp-0.1.2](http://rubygems.org/gems/bracecomp) can be used to perform brace expansion. Below is an example taken from the gem homepage:

```
require 'bracecomp'
p 'server-{a,b}-{07..10}'.expand
#=> ["server-a-07", "server-a-08", "server-a-09", "server-a-10", "server-b-07", "server-b-08", "server-b-09", "server-b-10"]
p 'zone-{a..c}'.expand
#=> ["zone-a", "zone-b", "zone-c"]
```

Comment: It would be better if you mention/explain what this is and/or link to the library(?) .